# trying to populate new columns with the following values but r giving me errors

Tags: r, dataframe, calculated-columns

I have a table named Taxi_Volume and I wanted to add new columns to it by calculating the mean,and other values.  I kept getting the following error.

As my first question here, I hope you understand the writing issue.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(Taxi_Volume)){
+   Taxi_Volume['Volume_mean'][i] <- mean(Taxi_Volume[1:i,3])
+   #Taxi_Volume['ChangeC'][i+1] <- Taxi_Volume['Volume_mean'][i]- Taxi_Volume$Trip.Total[i+1]- C
+   #Taxi_Volume['S(t)'][i+1] <- max(0,Taxi_Volume['S(t)'][i] + Taxi_Volume['ChangeC'][i+1])
+   
+ }
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, value = 25965.6666666667) : 
  new columns would leave holes after existing columns
In addition: Warning message:
In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Volume_mean", value = list(Volume_mean = c(20799,  :
  provided 2 variables to replace 1 variables
```

I was hoping to fill my new three columns with the values calculated based on the above loop.

Comment: You don't need a loop to do this and your syntax for accessing a column within a dataframe is incorrect.  Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including both test data and expected output so that we can eaily see what are trying to do.  At the moment, we can only guess...

Comment: From code I'd guess(!) you might be after something like `Taxi_Volume$Volume_mean <- dplyr::cummean(Taxi_Volume$vol)`